# Error prevents application from opening

Tags: google-app-maker

When I attempt to open an existing appmaker project, it fails to load and returns this message.

[image: error message]

Other appmaker projects load and build just fine. The issue exists for multiple users.

How can I restore my appmaker project if it continues to crash on opening?

Comment: This is a bug with AppMaker and pretty sure engineers are already working on it. We'll have to wait until it gets fixed.

Comment: Plus 1 on this one. It appears this is a bug with App Maker, and may be related to whatever update Google made to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what everyone in this post has been saying, it too is a bug in App Maker that seems to occur whenever there's a new update on the G-Suite. To check the status on any G-Suite related products including AppMaker, go on to this site https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=status to determine whether a particular G-Suite product is down or not.